# Grass r.out.gdal, wrong values when importing to QGis

Tags: qgis, gdal, grass-gis

I have a problem with export/import functionalities between Grass and QGis.

1. I create a raster file in Grass (with r.wind.sun, but that most likely does not matter)
2. It has the following properties:

   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Y1e2.png): [image: Value range in Grass from 0 to 100.]

**Important: Range of data min = 0.0[...] max= 100**

3. I export that raster with:

   r.out.gdal input=sample_input output=sample_output

The process decides to take float64 as datatype.
And exits without an error.
Beside the fact, that the color table cannot be written as described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101926/grass-raster-map-types-uint16-and-float64).

4. When I import that file to QGIS, the absolute values have changed:

[image]

**So the value range changed from approx. 0-100 to 0.00-2.9.**

As the mean and stdev state already: It is not an option to use integers only.

I tried to multiply the data with 10,000 in Grass, but after exporting I also get a value range between 0-3 in QGis.

**What can I change in the process to keep the original value range?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a user issue with your [computational region](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region): if you want to export the full map, be sure to set the computational region to the full map prior to export (`g.region rast=your_rastermap -p`). Then export.

Note that r.info reports the full map min/max while those of the actual computational region can differ from that. E.g., you have a DEM of Europe but set the computational region to Rome, hence in this case r.info will report the min/max of the full DEM while r.out.gdal only exports the Rome area which is way different. Just to illustrate the idea.

So the answer to "What can I change in the process to keep the original value range?" is that you want to set the computational region to the full map prior to exporting it.

BTW: I note that you have an "unfortunate" resolution of 0.9784..., perhaps you wanted 1.0 really?