# R.Series in QGIS 3.14.3 GRASS 7.6.1 returning no data value outputs only

Tags: raster, qgis-3, grass-gis, nodata

I'm using QGIS 3.14.3 with GRASS 7.6.1 and trying to add together the values for 3 raster layers using r.series as I'm told this handles no data values better than raster calculator. Please see log below as r.series is only returning no data values.

```
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'r.series' starting…
Input parameters:
{ '-n' : True, 'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META' : '', 'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT' : '', 'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : '332966.7752,400122.2567,344713.3291999999,567742.8156 [EPSG:27700]',
 'input' : ['C:/.../Bowland_Hazard.tif','C:/.../Bowland_Vulnerability.tif','C:/.../Bowland_Waterways_Classified.tif'], 'method' : [10], 
'output' : 'C:/Users/seansuzedielois/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_6bed28472c854ab889990fbc4a475879/c70921be43984837baaa5faad3656e83/output.tif', 'quantile' : '', 'range' : [0,0], 'weights' : '' }

g.proj -c proj4="+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +units=m +no_defs"
r.external input="C:\...\Bowland_Hazard.tif" band=1 output="rast_5dd7bc9666a9616" --overwrite -o
r.external input="C:\...\Bowland_Vulnerability.tif" band=1 output="rast_5dd7bc9666a9617" --overwrite -o
r.external input="C:\...\Bowland_Waterways_Classified.tif" band=1 output="rast_5dd7bc9666a9618" --overwrite -o
g.region n=567742.8156 s=344713.3291999999 e=400122.2567 w=332966.7752 res=30.0
r.series input=rast_5dd7bc9666a9616,rast_5dd7bc9666a9617,rast_5dd7bc9666a9618 -n method="sum" range="0,0" output=output7e2b59a143804b069736ec560da663f5 --overwrite
g.region raster=output7e2b59a143804b069736ec560da663f5
r.out.gdal -t -m input="output7e2b59a143804b069736ec560da663f5" output="C:\Users\seansuzedielois\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_6bed28472c854ab889990fbc4a475879\c70921be43984837baaa5faad3656e83\output.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
Starting GRASS GIS...
WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows
Cleaning up temporary files...
Executing <C:\Users\seansuzedielois\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_6bed28472c854ab889990fbc4a475879\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> ...
C:\Users\seansuzedielois\Documents>chcp 1252 1>NUL
C:\Users\seansuzedielois\Documents>g.proj -c proj4="+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +units=m +no_defs"
WARNING: Datum <Unknown_based_on_Airy_1830_ellipsoid> not recognised by GRASS and no parameters found
Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have multiple mapsets `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the region from the default
Projection information updated
C:\Users\seansuzedielois\Documents>r.external input="C:\...\Bowland_Hazard.tif" band=1 output="rast_5dd7bc9666a9616" --overwrite -o
Over-riding projection check
Reading band 1 of 1...
Link to raster map <rast_5dd7bc9666a9616> created.
C:\Users\seansuzedielois\Documents>r.external input="C:\...\Bowland_Vulnerability.tif" band=1 output="rast_5dd7bc9666a9617" --overwrite -o
Over-riding projection check
Reading band 1 of 1...
Link to raster map <rast_5dd7bc9666a9617> created.
C:\Users\seansuzedielois\Documents>r.external input="C:\...\Bowland_Waterways_Classified.tif" band=1 output="rast_5dd7bc9666a9618" --overwrite -o
Over-riding projection check
Reading band 1 of 1...
Link to raster map <rast_5dd7bc9666a9618> created.
C:\Users\seansuzedielois\Documents>g.region n=567742.8156 s=344713.3291999999 e=400122.2567 w=332966.7752 res=30.0
C:\Users\seansuzedielois\Documents>r.series input=rast_5dd7bc9666a9616,rast_5dd7bc9666a9617,rast_5dd7bc9666a9618 -n method="sum" range="0,0" output=output7e2b59a143804b069736ec560da663f5 --overwrite
0..3..6..9..12..15..18..21..24..27..30..33..36..39..42..45..48..51..54..57..60..63..66..69..72..75..78..81..84..87..90..93..96..99..100
C:\Users\seansuzedielois\Documents>g.region raster=output7e2b59a143804b069736ec560da663f5
C:\Users\seansuzedielois\Documents>r.out.gdal -t -m input="output7e2b59a143804b069736ec560da663f5" output="C:\Users\seansuzedielois\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_6bed28472c854ab889990fbc4a475879\c70921be43984837baaa5faad3656e83\output.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
ERROR 6: SetColorTable() only supported for Byte or UInt16 bands in TIFF format.
Checking GDAL data type and nodata value...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
Using GDAL data type <Float64>
Input raster map contains cells with NULL-value (no-data). The value -1.#IND will be used to represent no-data values in the input map. You can specify a nodata value with the nodata option.
Exporting raster data to GTiff format...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
r.out.gdal complete. File <C:\Users\seansuzedielois\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_6bed28472c854ab889990fbc4a475879\c70921be43984837baaa5faad3656e83\output.tif> created.
C:\Users\seansuzedielois\Documents>exit
Execution of <C:\Users\seansuzedielois\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_6bed28472c854ab889990fbc4a475879\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> finished.
Cleaning up temporary files...
Execution completed in 5.61 seconds
Results:
{'output': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':C:/Users/seansuzedielois/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_6bed28472c854ab889990fbc4a475879/c70921be43984837baaa5faad3656e83/output.tif, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'r.series' finished
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a small problem with the implementation of the GRASS `r.series` algorithm in QGIS:
The *Ignore values outside this range (lo,hi)* parameter is **not optional** (yet).

You need to explicitly specify values in those fields. Make sure that the pixel values of your input rasters are within that range.

---

A similar question was asked on January 31. The answer was not accepted and the bug was not reported:
[r.series - no output 'ERROR 6: SetColorTable() only supported for Byte or UInt16 bands in TIFF format.!](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310626/r-series-no-output-error-6-setcolortable-only-supported-for-byte-or-uint16)

I forgot that subject. Reviewing now again I find that fortunately Markus Neteler reported the error in QGIS, on March 3:
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/29269

The problem seems to be of a non-simple solution, however in recent days the team was working on it:
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/32922

Searching for more questions of the same type, I found that it was probably the problem that caused a question of August 23, 2018, in which I see that you have added a comment:
[r.series GRASS algorithm in QGIS 3.2 output no-data image](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293782/r-series-grass-algorithm-in-qgis-3-2-output-no-data-image)

---

*DISCLAIMER:   I am not part of the QGIS developer team, much less. I don't have academic or technical knowledge about programming. However, I am fascinated with the development of open source code by developer communities and with the free spread of knowledge.*